# jQuery is not working on button id in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

Below is my html table in which I m printing data from XML files and in status column corresponding every entry a button generated using angularJS directive ng-repeat.

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="detail in details" align="center">
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeID}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeName}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete Request" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

when I used jQuery function on ASP.net button using ID="btnDelete" the jQuery is not working in ng-repeat.

below is my angular JS and jQuery code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).children().toggleClass('active');
            $('[id$=btnDelete]').on("click", function () {
                alert("hi...");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('myDB.xml')
            .then(function (response) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                //$scope.details = response.data.UserDetail;
                $scope.details = [];
                var data = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
                $scope.details = data.UserDetail.Detail;
            });

        });
```

Even I have handled this issue in jQuery but still not working so please some one help me in this case

Comment: Generally when angular is loaded into your page it's better to use angular.element('item') when selecting a jquery element rather then $() and for click and other event functions it's better to use the ng event attributes

Comment: In fact that is probably your entire problem is that the jquery function runs before your ng-repeat runs so the on click function is never attached to the element

Comment: Why you are not using the `ng-click` directive? any specific reason to use the asp button control here? Are you going to write the server side button click handler too? @Binvention is correct, your jQuery event is not attached.

Comment: @Binvention, could you please explain this further with a demo? I can relate that better.

Comment: I'll add an example as a answer

Comment: @RahulSingh, Yes Rahul with this asp button control I need to update in XML file which is not possible with input control/Client control.

Comment: @VIVEKJAIN - Why it's not possible? You can make an ajax request to do that right? Why postback the complete page with asp button?

Answer (score 0):

Your button would like like this when assigning a on click function using angular

```
<button ng-click="function or expression"><\button>
```

That would fix your problem with it not running your function, then delete your jquery on click and instead have a function in your angular designed to handle the on click. then reference that function in the ng-click attribute. and the specific tag around the ng-click doesn't matter as it is supported by all tags in angular. For a more complete example of ng-click go [to the angular website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to Jquery change `<asp:Button ID="btnDelete"` to `<asp:Button class="btnDelete"` you should change to class because ID to be **unique**, it will not work in ng-repeat. Your Jquery will be as following:

  $(".btnDelete").on("click", function () {
              alert("hi...");
          });
- Recommendation: You should use ng-click event of angular

example:

HTML

```
 <input type="button" value="Click Me" ng-click="Addone()" />
```

AngularJs

```
 <script>  
   angular.module('MyForm', [])  
       .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {  
  $scope.count = 0; 
  $scope.Addone = function () {  
     $scope.count++;  
   };  
        }]);  
 </script>
```

You can create "btnDelete_Click" function for your code instead of "Addone" in my example code

See more [event ng-click in angularjs](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/tutorial-21-event-ng-click-in-angularjs.html)